# How i can get the userID from the table ASPNETDB.NET in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, userid

Hello can anyone help me how i can get the user id of a user?
If i write User.Identity.Name i'm getting the name of the user and if i write User.IsInRole i'm getting the role of the user. what i have to write in order to get the user id?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
Guid userId = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
```